# Appearance work properly in Emulator but not in Real Device

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

[Appearance look like this when I run in Emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kzws.png)

[But When I run in real device it look like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7De3.png)

see the link image for reference.

what seems to be the problem guys?

kindly ask me what code you want me to paste so you can check.

thanks!

Edited --

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/test_image"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/menu_display_image"
            android:src="@drawable/iinterior"></ImageView>

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:background="#AA000000"></View>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top|right"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/text_goes_here"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="30dp" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/fragment_button_center"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:background="@drawable/butt_purple"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:shadowColor="@android:color/white"
            android:shadowDx="1"
            android:shadowDy="1"
            android:shadowRadius="10"
            android:text="@string/add_to_my_menu"
            android:textSize="18dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/fragment_button_left"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:background="@drawable/butt_other"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:shadowColor="@android:color/white"
            android:shadowDx="1"
            android:shadowDy="1"
            android:shadowRadius="10"
            android:text="View Order State"
            android:textSize="18dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/description"
        android:textSize="20dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Are the screen of the emulator and your phone the same size ? The emulator looks like an tablet to me.

Comment: ^this and share your layouts too

Comment: @ahdgfd it looks like tablet cos its on landscape mode.

Comment: @Shaishav I already edit the code. please check thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please, read this in details: [Support multiple screens](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

You will see that layout has different look & feel depending on the screen characteristics...